# returning a null value from an index out of bounds c++ linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to return a null value if an index is out of bounds, or just stop the function from continuing. When I change `T&` to `T*` I can return a null value, but then I can't return curr->data at the end. If I'm using `T&` it won't allow me to use null. Any suggestions to returning a null value and stop the execution of the function. Should I throw an `Index Out of Bounds` Exception?

```
  T& operator [](int i) {
    if(i < 0 || i > this->size){
      std::cout << "Index out of bounds" << endl;
    }
    else{
      Node* curr = this->head;
      for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        curr = curr->next;
        j++;
      }
    return curr->data;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, throw an [`out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exception.  References aren't meant to support "null" values... if you want such a sentinel stick to a pointer.

Comment: @Tony_D When I do this, my program terminates after I throw the exception. Is there a way to allow for the program to continue executing after the exception is thrown?

Comment: @kevorski if you throw an exception, you will have to catch it somewhere, or else the program terminates.

Comment: @kevorski: yes... you can use `try { ...X... } catch (const std::exception& e) { std::cerr << "caught exception " << e.what() << '\n'; }`, replacing `...X...` with the code that might throw (i.e. the code that uses your `operator[]`.  It's not a bad habit to put a `try/catch` statement in `main` so you at least get to read the exception messages for exceptions that aren't caught in other functions.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should make  condition like 
if(i < 0 || i > this->size-1) 
because when accessing last node it should be getting next pointer as null

Answer (score 0):

References are not nullable.  The proper thing to do if the parameter is invalid (i.e. out of bounds), and therefore you cannot fulfill the contract, is to throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is one "problem" faced by some standard library containers, specifically `std::vector`, `std::array`, `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`. How do they remedy this?

For `std::vector` and `std::array`, they just let it be, let undefined behavior do the dirty job and make your life miserable (see, just like in real life doing bad things leads to bad karma). For `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` they return a new element if such an index/key is not found in their current elements. This comes at the expense of disabling such behavior when the container is `const`, as to why you'll see below.

So, what do you do? If I were to decide, I would go with undefined behavior. Another option would be to throw an [exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) just like when calling `std::vector::at()` (aka the "safe" `operator[]`). The throw-an-exception solution isn't appropriate for a `const` version of `std::(unordered_)map::operator[]` for it will be inconsistent with its non-throwing non-`const` sibling.

Comment: What would give the impression that an `operator[]` might be constant time? You mentioned `std::map` yourself where it is log(n).

Comment: @ArneMertz Ah well, you know this war between vector and list gets on your head sometimes.

Comment: @MarkGarcia: `std::string` is another for yoru list.  Re "go with undefined behaviour" - it's not obvious what that might mean in this situation, but I take it to mean "save the time to check `size()` and just go straight into the code currently in the `else` block - letting it crash if it dereferences the final `nullptr`.  That's definitely an option, but shifts the "null reference vs `throw`" question to be about how to write the `at()` function.  Re "isn't appropriate for", given `(unordered_)map` will likely never have a `const operator[]` that's hard to draw insight from...?